# What is downloadfile.bin?

Tags: download-manager

At random times, Download manager start downloading series of files named as downlaodfile.bin, downloadfile-1.bin and so on.

I got this issue since today morning. And it happened twice today.

What is this file and why it is getting downloaded? Thanks.

**Device information**

Device: Moto G4+
Android version: 7.0 Nougat

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I too faced this today mor. I use moto g3.. I noticed the download and turned off my WiFi and after few mins it disappeared from downloads.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: No I haven't rooted my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Moto G3 with Lineage OS (July month build). I had the same issue of auto downloading which started two days ago.

What I have observed is the downloading takes place when I turn on mobile data after 10 AM in morning or 10 PM at night. The files are not shown in ES Explorer app, but I can see those files queued  if I use in-built file manager of Lineage OS. I tried to see which app was using mobile data at that time using [My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) app and it showed that *Media Storage* system app was using the internet.

Comment: I mistakenly flagged your post as NAA for its ending posted as a question, but now that I see it the post has value IMO so I have removed the part concerning *your* question. You can post that as a question separately.

Comment: i am new to this site and joined today after seeing this thread for this problem. so i dont know much about the procedures followed here. thanks for the edit

Comment: So does this mean, my device is infected?

Comment: have you tried any anti virus to scan it ?